# django user authenticated (not authenticated )

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to create a simple Django authentication (register/login/logout) but I have problems.
if complete login successfully then app go to next page with name `mypage` because I have define in my `settings.py` that line : `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/mypage'`.

but in the new page user is not authenticated user(my user stay authenticated only in the `"/login"`and`"/register"`page but not in `home` and `mypage` )

any idea why I have wrong ?

here the code :

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.home),
url(r'^mypage/$', views.mypage),
url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}),
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': '/login/'}),
url(r'^register/$', views.register),
url(r'^register/success/$', views.register_success)
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html')

def mypage(request):
    return render_to_response('home2.html')
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/mypage'
```

html 1 :

```
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
         <li>
            <a href="/logout">LogOut</a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
         <li>
            <a href="/login">Login</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
```

html 2 :

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
 <a href="#" class="lg">Start</a>
  {% else %}
  <p>Please Login to start</p>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Include views.py

Comment: @Astik Anand where Include views.py  ?

Comment: I mean include your views also here in question.

Comment: @Astik Anand that is all my view with register

Comment: @ Astik Anand any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `render_to_response` you need add user to context manual, or you can use `render` with request, in this case `user` will be added to your template context

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def mypage(request):
    return render_to_response('home2.html', {'user': request.user})
```

Comment: I think so working now thank you that need to do for all pages where I want to have user authenticated like this 
     `return render_to_response('home2.html', {'user': request.user}) ` ?

Comment: if you want to use `render_to_response`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

In **urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    . . .. 
]
```

In **login.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   <h2>Login</h2>
   <form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <button type="submit">Login</button>
 </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: is the some again user is not authenticated in mypage..that as `auth_views` must be use for all regex

Comment: Not required to do that.

Comment: Try to print something after login to make sure it works, something like `<h2>{{user.username}}</h2>` and let me know.

Comment: Have you tried to print `username` on your `home2.html`, what it says??

Comment: I can see user olny in login and register page